# Set custom port tcp, just to login cms

Tags: tcp, connection, content-management-system, port

I want to set custom port tcp to login cms for example wordpress.

¿This is possible?

(but set normal port 80 to entire site)

For example in cpanel whm, there have different  ports 2086 not ssl and 2087 ssl

With tool like ipset (iptables in linux) can I block entire contry according to range ip and port, for example can I just allow my country to request specified port.

Another better method is use layer 2 firewall like google compute engine and block ranges of ips relation to specified port.

Sorry for this question maybe is not good.

Again:

¿Can I do this in a cms like wordpress?

Note: I know about Deny all in .htaccess.
      I know about set just ssl to wp-admin.
      I know i can change to rute wp-admin   another alias name.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a simple bash script to download ip addresses for a particular country (represented as a zone) from ipdeny.com.  The bash command would be something like:

```
wget -qNP [dir] http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/XX.zone
```

Where [dir] is the directory you wish to store the zone file containing the list of ip addresses for the country; and XX is the two character country zone code.

You can then read the ip addresses into an ipset using the strategy described at:https://www.hueyise.com/index.php/linux-dynamic-ip-address-blocking... however, this strategy applies specifically to dynamically blocking malicious ip addresses (e.g., hackers) that are discovered during operations and blocking them immediately.

I successfully implement a tailored version of this strategy to automatically download ip addresses for certain countries once per day, and then read the ip addresses into an ipset defined for blocking inbound/outbound accesses by these countries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my question is relation to how to set tcp socket port to cms like wordpres.